# How to configure Kafka type mapping using spring kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've looked at the documentation and found this:

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=cat:com.mycat.Cat,hat:com.myhat.Hat
```

My producer properties:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-server=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer 
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=com.producerservice.dto.UserDTO:UserDTO
```

The maven install run successfully.

The consumer properties:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=com.consumerservice.dto.UserDTO:UserDTO
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
```

This one maven install failed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load: UserDTO for com.consumerservice.dto.UserDTO
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer.createMappings(JsonSerializer.java:188) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.createMappings(JsonDeserializer.java:438) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.configure(JsonDeserializer.java:418) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:716) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
```

Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types),
on a consumer side a token still should go first (before a full classname):

> consumerProps.put(JsonDeSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "cat:com.yourcat.Cat, hat:com.yourhat.hat");

So:
`spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=UserDTO:com.consumerservice.dto.UserDTO`

Comment: Well, I tried this and got different error but becuase your answer is valid I create a new one :-(

Comment: will wait for new question =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747642/how-to-configure-kafka-type-mapping-using-spring-boot-maven-build-success-but-i