# How to configure Kafka type mapping using spring boot, maven build success but contain errors?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I've looked at the documentation and found this:

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=cat:com.mycat.Cat,hat:com.myhat.Hat
```

My producer properties:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-server=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer 
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=com.producerservice.dto.UserDTO:UserDTO
```

The maven install run successfully.

The consumer properties:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=UserDTO:com.consumerservice.dto.UserDTO
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
```

maven is successful but there is an error, I don't undestand what it's passed when error exists:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
```

And the error continued, reporting about the producer class:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.producerservice.dto.UserDTO]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.producerservice.dto.UserDTO
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:142) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:572) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1439) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.producerservice.dto.UserDTO
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:466) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:138) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

class not found for the producer class? of course it's not found I'm in the consumer

UPDATE

I have changed the producer properties to the follow:

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=UserDTO:com.producerservice.dto.UserDTO
```

problem still persist with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this solved at least the maven build:

```
userDto:com.my.example.UserDTO
```

I had

```
userDTO
```

So, the token was the problem, token is the variable name
that is used in your listener consume method.

To understand that the main issue was with token this question helped:
[what is token in class type mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206790/how-to-map-types-using-properties-file-in-kafka)

But that alone didn't fix, I had to stop zookeeper and broker delete all logs and
guess what the build is successful on both side.
Message will send tomorrow, too tired.

Answer (score 0):

> of course it's not found I'm in the consumer

Your producer and consumer need to share a dependency of your data classes.

You have a runtime error which Maven cannot detect since you have dynamic class-loading in your Kafka deserializer, but it could detect it, if you added `UserDTO` into your `@KafkaListener` method parameter.

Comment: listener has this public void consume(UserDTO user) {   of course, so you saying I need have a domain depency which include the class? but it is not recommened.

Comment: Who says this is not recommended? How else will you consume objects of that type?

Comment: dependency is not required, have a look at my answer, tomorrow I'll check the runtime, too tired.

Comment: microservices need to do decoupling, but I agree that a change in the message might requried a change in both sides :-)